# Swift firebase timestamp cant show

Tags: ios, swift

I am able to retrieve and convert my timestamp that I got from firebase(i did a breakpoint at that line and my time shows **5/3/18,3:05 PM**, so it's fine), below is my code:

```
    func loadMsg() {
    let toId = user!.id!
    let fromId = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
    let chatRoomId = (fromId < toId) ? fromId + "_" + toId : toId + "_" + fromId

    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("privateMessages").child(chatRoomId)
    ref.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in

        ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded, with: { (datasnap) in
            let lastMsgTime = (datasnap.value as! [String: AnyObject])["timestamp"] as? Double

            // to get timestamp and convert to date and time
            let x = lastMsgTime!
            let date = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: x)
            let formatter = DateFormatter()
            formatter.dateStyle = .short
            formatter.timeStyle = .short
            let time = formatter.string(from: date as Date)

            self.message.timestamp = time //HERE IT CRASHES!!!!!

        if let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {

            self.messages.removeAll()

            for data in snapshot {

                let newMsg = Message(dictionary: data.value as! [String: AnyObject])

                self.messages.append(newMsg)

            }
        }
            })
        DispatchQueue.main.async {self.tableView.reloadData()}
    }
}
```

However it crashes at the line which i commented above, i was supposed to show it on my `tableviewCell` in my message cell. My tableView cell was done by xib which looks like :

[image]

and the code of my `tableviewCell` would be:

```
{

    self.message = message

    if message.fromId == currentUser {

        sentView.isHidden = false

        sentMsgLabel.text = message.textMessages

        receivedMsgLabel.text = ""

        receivedView.isHidden = true

        timeReceived.text = message.timestamp

        timeSent.text = message.timestamp

    } else {

        sentView.isHidden = true

        sentMsgLabel.text = ""

        receivedMsgLabel.text = message.textMessages

        receivedMsgLabel.isHidden = false

        timeReceived.text = message.timestamp

        timeSent.text = message.timestamp
    }
}
```

So, why would it crash and says

> "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an
>   Optional value"

my message class code:

```
    class Message: NSObject {

    var fromId: String?
    var textMessages: String?
    var timestamp: String?
    var toId: String?
    var message: Message!
    var _messageKey: String!


    init(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
        self.fromId = dictionary["fromId"] as? String
        self.textMessages = dictionary["textMessages"] as? String
        self.toId = dictionary["toId"] as? String
        self.timestamp = dictionary["timestamp"] as? String
    }

    init(messageKey: String, postData: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>) {

        _messageKey = messageKey

        if let message = postData["textMessages"] as? String {

            textMessages = message
        }

        if let sender = postData["fromId"] as? String {

            fromId = sender
        }
    }

}
```

I believe there isnt any issue with my firebase, main problem is at the tableview cell, why wouldnt it show?

Comment: Hey William, just saw your now deleted Meta question about downvotes without comments. Many of us agree what you describe is not an ideal situation, but it's a really tough problem to solve. Here's some more background discussion: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-commenting-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggesting-such-s Long story short, please don't feel too discouraged by the occasional downvote; and do feel free to ask on Meta if you have doubts about whether a specific question is a good fit for the site. (Downvotes there don't take away reputation.)

Comment: yea, read it and deleted it. Understand this is a tough problem to solve, thx @Pekka웃

Comment: @WilliamLoke Where did you initialize `self.message` ? And I can see you're using `NSDate` in swift please don't do this use only `Date` instead.

Comment: @TheTiger Hi, old friend..i have edited the question, you should be able to see my message initialisation now

Comment: @WilliamLoke I can see 'Message`'s class structure but still can not find where you initialize `self.message` before passing the `timestamp` to it. I'm talking about `self.message.timestamp = time` line.

Comment: in my tableviewCell, i had a line timeReceived.text = message.timestamp and timeSent.text = message.timestamp
, is it the initialisation?

Answer (score 0):

Try to get timestamp from server like this:

```
ServerValue.timestamp()
```

Comment: there isnt any issue with firebase. I got the time.. i do not know why my app will crash at the line which I commented above

Comment: Which exception it throws? And can you show what is `self.message` and where it declared?

Comment: it crashed with saying "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Comment: self.message is a class which I made for Message

Comment: `self.message.timestamp` is a `Date` type? Maybe try to store raw timestamp in your `self.message.timestamp` and then format it from there ?